# Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line) error in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I get this error with the below code (last line): `Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)`

```
private val myClass: Class<String>
  get() = String::class.java

myClass: Class<*> = extras!!.getSerializable("myClass") as Class<Activity?>
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason why IDE show this error is because your variable **myClass** have two types `Class<String>` and `Class<Activity?>`.

I guess what you are trying to do is retrieve an extra from a Bundle and casting into a correct object to use it.

So here is some pseduo codes:

```kotlin
private lateinit var myClass: Class<Activity>
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 myClass = intent?.extras!!.getSerializable("myClass") as Class<Activity>
}
```

this way at least there isn't anymore error, however you may need to consider the **cast safety** since you need to check it.

Comment: i get this error now : `kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type java.lang.Class<android.app.Activity>`

Comment: then take it as `Class<Activity?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to type `myClass` in an assignment (type annotations in assignments can only be used on the right side of the `=`).

The compiler assumes that you mean to write a second expression (starting from `:`), since `myClass` is already an expression of type `Class<String>`, and informs you that you should use `;` to separate expressions on the same line.

Type annotations for Variables can only be used in declarations.

As a side note: That assignment won't work anyway, since `myClass` is immutable (keyword `val`) and the types are incompatible too (`Class<Activity?>` is not a `Class<String>`).